# How to find CompletableFuture completed execeptionally

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I am using CompletableFuture and have a question on exception handling.

I have a code like this, if any of validate() or process() method throws an exception then it is handled by the ExceptionHandler. However when I am using the CompletableFuture like this then the exception thrown is wrapped in CompletionException. May I know how can I make sure that my ExceptionHandler is called there instead of getting CompletionException?

```
CompletableFuture<Response> response = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> {
                    validationService.validate(request);
                    return myService.process(request, headers);
                });
```

Comment: What is this `ExceptionHandler` that you're referring to?

Comment: Spring @ExceptionHandler

Comment: i don't think so Spring @ExceptionHandler will work for this, please double check it

Comment: Spring @ExceptionHandler can handle CompletionException

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before calling `get()` on `CompletableFuture` call this method `isCompletedExceptionally`, will return true if it completes with exception

```
public boolean isCompletedExceptionally()
```

> Returns true if this CompletableFuture completed exceptionally, in any way. Possible causes include cancellation, explicit invocation of completeExceptionally, and abrupt termination of a CompletionStage action.

You can also add exceptional block for the completableFuture, so while executing task if any exception occurs it will execute the exceptionally with exception an input argument

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> "Success")
                                   .exceptionally(ex->"failed");
```

In the above example if any exception occurs executing `supplyAsync` **failed** will return or else **Success** is returned

Comment: Should call `isCompletedExceptionally()` after get() or before? IMO, seems after get() since that's the only blocking call.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, by calling the following code, it will solve my problem

```
try {
            response.join();
        }
        catch(CompletionException ex) {
            try {
                throw ex.getCause();
            }

            catch(Throwable impossible) {
                throw impossible;
            }
        }
```